# Issue with iOS viewport in Google Apps Script

Tags: ios, google-apps-script

I have found an issue with how Google Apps script HtmlService is being displayed on iOS devices.  If the content of the html is greater in height than the viewport, the iOS devices do not enable scrolling.  Is there any way to force this?  The following code will reproduce the problem on iOS devices.

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html')
      .evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width,initial-scale=1").setTitle("Whatever")

}


"html" file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Prep Notes Viewer-Editor</title> 



<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >

</head>


<body>

<div id="output">
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Line <br>
Last Line
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should publish your script and give anonymous access to everyone and post the like here so people can test it.

Comment: Here's a link.  https://script.google.com/d/1j2I3Gr6qXbN5PQjq4tBIb2dex4mVkNRYBLf5mLiCWCVlFYi2-MC7QY9Y/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way.

Add a div element right after the body (let's call it #backgroundBox), surrounding the entire body html, then set the css of that div element to:

```
#backgroundBox{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

and again the html would look like this:

```
"html" file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Prep Notes Viewer-Editor</title> 



<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >

</head>


<body>
<div id="#backgroundBox">
  <div id="output">
    Line <br>
    Line <br>
    MORE LINES
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Note: Inertial scrolling for iOS devices with this fix.  If you add -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; the problem returns where you cannot scroll at all.